# Watch items that being added to the sql table, wpf

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have application that generates a lot of numbers and writes them to table in sql Database.
When the process writes the numbers to the table , I give an option to watch the numbers that have been already written to the DB. I want to do it "Live".
The thing is that I have a DLL that handles the DB management , and in my UI I use this DLL. So I cant bind the ListBox to the table of numbers because the UI doesn't "know" that table.... What could be the best solution for that?

Comment: is the same application producing the data and presenting that in the UI?

Comment: One application is presenting the data and another is producing....two different projects. The UI project is using the Data project . To produce the data I use LinqToSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are 3 solutions that come to my mind:

- poll periodically the DB from the user facing app. So there is a thread running which every x seconds picks up the values from the DB, and then transfers them to the client.
- You can use the Sql Notification Services in case you are using sql server to push the changes to the client, then you don't have to poll.
- the last option, I guess will be an overkill for you, but the producing "app" can notify the displaying app via e.g. a message queue, or a WCF call.

Imho No1 fits for you best, but I cannot judge more precisly because I don't know expected load, ....